# how to verify changes on objects after memory allocation

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this code

```
classX* arrayX=new classEx[3];

// ..some code.. add and remove object to the array

//now need to check if at least one element was inserted into arrayEx

if (arrayX!=NULL){
  std::cout<<"The array is not empty, proceed";
  //some code
}
else{
  std::cout<<"Not even one element was inserted.Insert at least one new object";
}
```

My doubt is, Is that  `if (arrayX!=NULL)` routine good to check for insertions?Please not suggest stl implementation(like vector). it must be that way

Comment: What you need is an `std::vector`.

Comment: @mikedu95 I disagree, I really disagree with people that suggest the use of `std:vector` over raw pointers. He is of course trying to understand pointers, etc, so why should you suggest him to take a shortcut?

Comment: To the OP: you should also know that according to the standard, `new` never returns NULL.

Comment: @nbro *He is of course trying to understand pointers*  -- Let the OP decide what he / she is attempting to do.  Maybe they don't care if it's vector or raw pointers, but were led to the pointer code by reading a very poor or outdated C++ book on "dynamic arrays".

Comment: @kfx C++ has a standard? Strange.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I guess that newbies that start using C++ do it not because of its nice data structures, but because they can "break the bit".

Comment: *Please not suggest stl implementation(like vector). it must be that way*  -- There is no such thing as "insertion" with the code you posted.  You allocated 3 items, it will remain as 3 items.  It isn't going to turn into 4 items unless you reallocate for 4 items.

Comment: @nbro And maybe a newbie is trying to get their whiz-bang program done, and instead of concentrating on the whiz-bangness, they're stuck on a dynamic array (when they could have used vector).

Comment: @gustav2704: without a vector, your array already contains 3 objects at creation. Cannot contain less nor more. So what do you call an "insertion" since ?

Comment: @kfx minor nitpick: if you use the nothrow overload of operator new, then it does indeed return `nullptr` on allocation failure.

Comment: so let's change the word insertion by assignment. it s a new value inside the array what I meant. ie `arrayX[0]=newvalue;`

Answer (score 1):

There are no insertions.  When you do

```
classX* arrayX=new classEx[3];
```

You create an array of 3 elements.  It will always be 3 elements unless you change the pointer to a different array.  One thing you could do is use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and then check to see if it is empty or not.

```
std::vector<some_type> foo;
// add and remove items from the vector
if (!foo.empty())
    // do something
else
    // no elements
```

Comment: please I need to solve it with pointers and no STL. Thank you friend

Comment: @gustav2704 Then I am not sure what you want to do.  You create an array of 3 elements so it will always have 3 elements.  One thing you could do is keep a counter of the number of elements that are actually being used but that seems wrong to me.  I would actually have to see your requirements to be able to suggest a different approach.

Comment: the purpose is to know if the array was charged with new data or not. The memory was allocated but it  maybe has not been assigned to any object. I need to check that. I don not know if the way I did was good or not. How do I check for changes? is the counter the only solution?

Comment: @gustav2704 It is not the only solution.  You could make you own vector or list and use that.  I have a suspiscion that is the point of the assignment

Comment: and any solution with no STL containers? @NathanOliver